# Are these two SPARQL 1.0 queries equivalent?

Tags: sparql

I'm querying a Mulgara triple store with the following two queries, trying to return subjects that do not match certain values. I'm limited to whatever parts of SPARQL 1.0 that Mulgara implements, and I'm curious if these two queries are effectively the same, or if there are behavioral differences that I'm not see in my results.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Query 1:

```
PREFIX fedora-model:        <info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#>
PREFIX fedora-rels-ext: <info:fedora/fedora-system:def/relations-external#>

SELECT ?pids
FROM <#ri>
WHERE {
    { ?pids fedora-model:hasModel <info:fedora/islandora:sp_large_image_cmodel> }
    UNION
    { ?pids fedora-model:hasModel <info:fedora/islandora:bookCModel> }
    UNION
    { ?pids fedora-model:hasModel <info:fedora/islandora:collectionCModel> }
    UNION
    { ?pids fedora-model:hasModel <info:fedora/islandora:compoundCModel> }
    UNION
    { ?pids fedora-model:hasModel <info:fedora/islandora:sp-audioCModel> }
    UNION
    { ?pids fedora-model:hasModel <info:fedora/islandora:sp_videoCModel> }
    UNION
    { ?pids fedora-model:hasModel <info:fedora/islandora:sp_basic_image> }
    UNION
    { ?pids fedora-model:hasModel <info:fedora/islandora:sp_pdf> }
    UNION
    { ?pids fedora-model:hasModel <info:fedora/islandora:oralhistoriesCModel> }
}
```

and Query 2:

```
PREFIX fedora-model:     <info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#>
PREFIX fedora-rels-ext:  <info:fedora/fedora-system:def/relations-external#>

SELECT ?pids
FROM <#ri>
WHERE {
  ?pids fedora-model:hasModel ?models .
  FILTER (!regex(str(?models), "pageCModel") &&
          !regex(str(?models), "FedoraObject-3.0") &&
          !regex(str(?models), "transformCModel") &&
          !regex(str(?models), "ContentModel-3.0")) .
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "equivalent"? I mean, both queries might return the same resultset, but clearly we do **not** know the data, thus, we cannot judge if your `regex` based exclusions do exclude all other models. Moreover, I do not understand why you use `regex` instead of using the URIs, i.e. `FILTER (?models !=  <info:fedora/pageCModel> && ... )` - why do you decide on using `regex` on the URIs here? Regarding performance, the second query does a full scan while the first would be able to use `pos` index (if exists, I do not know Mulgara triple store at all)

Comment: @UninformedUser - great points, thank you very much for the response. I should have included data, but I think you've pointed a larger issue: I didn't realize that I could use `=` or `!=` on `?models` and the URIs. 

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no, these are not equivalent. Some of of the reasons why include:

- The former has an explicit list of model values to *include*, while the latter attempts to *exclude* values. Depending on the data, the two queries may return very different results
- The latter query uses a REGEX on the string value of ?models, but does not:

  - verify that the values of ?models is an IRI (it could be a literal that satisfies the filter conditions, for example)
  - verify that the REGEX is matching at the end of the string (I presume this is the intent)

And as a comment already mentions above, the use of REGEX will likely also have significant impact on query performance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know for certain whether the queries are equivalent is by running "exploratory" queries.

Here is a query to find out all the models there:

```
SELECT distinct ?models FROM <#ri> WHERE 
{ ?pids fedora-model:hasModel ?models}
```

With this you will have all the models. You can then find out if you are missing specifying any other models.

An alternative to using  '=' is to use the sameTerm function. The sameTerm function works on IRIs, whereas '=' compares both strings and literals too. Using sameTerm will have a slightly better response time.

```
PREFIX fedora-model:     <info:fedora/fedora-system:def/model#>
PREFIX fedora-rels-ext:  <info:fedora/fedora-system:def/relations-external#>
SELECT ?pids
FROM <#ri>
WHERE {
  ?pids fedora-model:hasModel ?models .
  FILTER (!sameTerm(?models, <info:fedora/islandora:pageCModel> ) &&
          !sameTerm(?models, <info:fedora/islandora:pageCModel> )) 
}
```